# meaning of Off- Resource Choice condition in the seize block

Tags: anylogic

I got a question concerning the Ressource selection in the seize block.

In Anylogic there is the possibility to choose:
Off (chooses some matching unit) — The dispatching policy is not applied.

If there are multiple choices, is the allocation based on probability?  [image: descripton AnyLogic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that anylogic will choose any resource available and after doing it, you don't have the right to complain about the resource that was selected.

But this doesn't mean that it won't choose the resource based on your resource choice condition, if you decided to customize the resource choice... but among all the resources that fit your resource choice condition, you can get any available, and you can't complain about it :)

It has to be noted, that having off saves computational time compared to for example finding the closest unit